# Performing binary logistic regression with equal number of cases and non-cases

Tags: logistic, sampling

The best way to ask my question is to present an example scenario:

Let's say that the outcome of interest is lung cancer (1 = lung cancer; 0 = no lung cancer) and a researcher has 200k records (where 20k patients have lung cancer (cases) and 180k patients do NOT have lung cancer (non-cases)). Since only 10% of patients (20/200k) in the sample data have lung cancer, a researcher uses a random sample of 20k from the patients that do NOT have lung cancer. By doing so, the researcher would have a sample of 20k patients with lung cancer and 20k patients without lung cancer in their sample (the sample is reduced from 200k to 40k records).

Are there any benefits to performing binary logistic regression with equal number of cases and non-cases when the actual distribution of the outcome is not equal? Or does this bias model estimates/predictive power?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is there anything to prevent you from weighting the subsample?

Comment: I agree with whuber. There will be absolutely no impact if (1) the sample is weighted to scale back to 200K, and (2) the subsample is representative of the full sample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you select the equal number of cases and non-cases, it will bias the model.  For example, suppose that the features have zero correlation with the outcome, and the dataset is very large.  The model will predict the same probability of lung cancer for all patients.  If you select equal number of positive and negative example, the predicted probability will be 0.5, while in reality it is 0.1 .

Comment: Thank you @user31265, this is what I assumed, but a colleague of mine wanted to know for sure and this thoroughly answers the question! Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Lets say $Y$ is your disease and $X$ are your covariates. Technically you shouldn't be able to model the probability of disease (since this is a case control study; you fixed the margins, the probability of disease in your sample is 0.5).

However, there was a landmark paper in 1979 by Prentice and Pyke (http://biomet.oxfordjournals.org/content/66/3/403.abstract) that shows that modeling $Y|X$ in logistic regression gives you same estimates as modeling $X|Y$.

So it does not bias model estimates/predictive power.

Comment: Good point, @Benjamin, so the take away from your response is that this is an acceptable practice? In terms of benefits, models with 40k records would run much faster than models with 200k records, so this is good news, if that is the case! Thanks!

Comment: Well hold on there. More samples means, more power. It might be more difficult computationally, but that shouldn't be a reason to exclude samples (typically reason is something like money/time).

Comment: I agree, I am just curious about what the differences between using a reduced sample with 50% cases and 50% non-cases (40k records) instead of 10% cases and 90% non-cases (200k records) are, if any.